# Docker images wont run in background

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I created my first Dockerfile, but when i run the command

```
sudo docker ps
```

The container isn't running in the background, here's my dockerfile:

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM debian:jessie

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER <Qop>

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

################## BEGIN INSTALLATION ######################

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
vim \
apache2

##################### INSTALLATION END #####################

# Expose the default port
EXPOSE 81

# Default port to execute the entrypoint (MongoDB)
CMD ["--port 81"]

# Set default container command
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `bash` entrypoint, bash will exit as soon as stdin returns an end of file. So you leave it running, you need to start it with `docker run -itd image-name`. The `-i` makes it interactive, `-t` assigns a tty, and `-d` detaches. That keeps the stdin open on the container and allows you to attach or exec commands against the container.

Follow up: I just saw your command `--port 81` which when run as a command on `bash` will give you an invalid option. If you need to run mongo with that as an option, you'll need a different entry point.

Comment: Thank you, this make a lot of sense!